# publish subscriber channel - do consumers run in parallel

Tags: spring-integration

I have a integration flow that seems like this

a). a poller dropping messages in a queued channel

b). a service activator picking up messages from the queue and I have specified an executor on the poller for this service activator

c). the service activator sends the processed messages to a publish subscriber channel

d). the publish subscribe channel then has multiple consumers which receive the message for further processing

okay so what I am wondering is what role does the executor plays in this flow

a) so my service activator that polls from the queue has an executor which lets say has a fixed pool of 10 threads and lets say I have max-messages-per-poll as 5 so im assuming 5 of new messages will be processed in one go by 5 separate threads from the pool.

b) assuming thats correct then what happens when the 5 different messages reach the publish-subscriber channel. Lets say this pub-sub channel has 3 subscribers .. does that means internally 3 new threads will be spawned to asynchronously pass the incoming message to the 3 different subscribers .. so that the subscribers/consumers can do their processing of the message in parallel. I guess at this point it gets a little fuzzy on how things are gonna be processed. basically I guess im wondering is if the consumers are provided the message and the consumers chains run in parallel .. and if thats the case where is the executor for that

any comments would be appreciated
Thanks

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++

Based on below input I was trying this out

```
 <int:service-activator 
                    input-channel="filesIn"
                    output-channel="readyFiles"
                    ref="handler">
        <int:poller fixed-delay="3000" max-messages-per-poll="3" />
    </int:service-activator>

    <int:publish-subscribe-channel id="readyFiles" task-executor="executor">            
    </int:publish-subscribe-channel>

    <int:service-activator 
                            id="consumer1"
                            input-channel="readyFiles"
                            ref="handler"
                            />

    <int:service-activator 
                            id="consumer2"
                            input-channel="readyFiles"
                            ref="handler"
                            />

    <int:service-activator 
                            id="consumer3"
                            input-channel="readyFiles"
                            ref="handler"
                            />

    <task:executor id="executor" pool-size="10" rejection-policy="CALLER_RUNS"/>
```

my handler simply slows things down a bit

```
public void handle(File file) throws InterruptedException{
    log.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " executing for file " + file.getName() + " ...");
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    log.debug(Thread.currentThread().getName() + " completed for file " + file.getName());
}
```

because I am using a task executor on the pub-sub channel i was expecting that all 3 consumes should be started together but instead the result is sequential invocation

output

```
18:44:11.000 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][com.test.Handler] task-scheduler-3 executing for file 1.txt ...
18:44:14.001 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][com.test.Handler] task-scheduler-3 completed for file 1.txt
18:44:14.002 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][com.test.Handler] task-scheduler-3 executing for file 2.txt ...
18:44:17.002 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][com.test.Handler] task-scheduler-3 completed for file 2.txt
18:44:17.002 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][com.test.Handler] task-scheduler-3 executing for file 3.txt ...
18:44:20.002 DEBUG [task-scheduler-3][com.test.Handler] task-scheduler-3 completed for file 3.txt
```

each subscriber is invoked after the previous one has completed.

Comment: had to change a few things around but below answer basically helped understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`<publish-subscribe-channel>` has `task-executor` option to initiate handler invocation within threads of that `Executor`. That means that your subscribers might process the message in parallel. But, of course, there is no guaranty, as it depends on `Executor` nature and state.

I think this snapshot from source code (`BroadcastingDispatcher`) should help you:

```
for (final MessageHandler handler : handlers) {
    if (this.executor != null) {
        this.executor.execute(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                invokeHandler(handler, messageToSend);
            }
        });
        dispatched++;
    }
    else {
        if (this.invokeHandler(handler, messageToSend)) {
            dispatched++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok so if the pub-sub channel has an executor then it would use that otherwise the caller thread which in this case is already a executor thread coming from poller .. right ? Does it makes more sense to have the executor on the pub-sub channel instead of the service activtor thats picking up messages from queue and passing to pub-sub channel .. but in that case the poller is single threaded and is picking up one message at a time .. i feel like my current flow is better coz the poller uses executor and pub-sub can benefit from that too because it executes in the caller thread of serv-activator

Comment: No. You misunderstood it. Your poller picks up one message, but pub-sub populate several messages for each subscriber. And without executor they all will be processed in the cycle, within the same caller's thread. In your case it is that one poller thread. Switch on the DEBUG for Spring Integration with `[%t]` and you'll how it works.

Comment: okay that makes sense but one thing I am still confused about is what is the point or benefit of using an executor on a poller .. doesnt seems like that helps in any way